# multiplication table python nested loop not printing full table

Tags: python

This is my code for my multiplication table so far. I am a bit confused as to how to continue to finish this problem, basically I need to be able to print a multiplication table with this format for any number between 1 and 9:

```
1  2    3   4   5
  --------------------------
  1|    1   2   3   4   5
  2|    2   4   6   8   10
  3|    3   6   9   12  15
  4|    4   8   12  16  20
  5|    5   10  15  20  25


x = int(input("enter a number 1-9: "))

output = ""


for x in range(1 ,x+1):
    output +=str(x) +"|\t"
    for y in range(1,x+1):
        output += str(y * x) +"\t"
    output +="\n"

print(output)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are replacing the value of `x` in the loop, instead you should use a different name for looping parameter:

```
output = ' '.join([f" {i}" for i in range(1, x+1)]) + "\n"
output += '---' * x + "\n"
for i in range(1, x+1):
    output += str(i) + "| "
    for y in range(1, x+1):
        output += str(y * i) + " "
    output += "\n"
```

Comment: when I do this and say, input 3, it prints everything perfect except for the top part which I need, its the top layer which is seperated by the ---

Comment: Hi Kamal, I updated my answer to write the top layer also.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop variable should have a different name, other than `x`. The value of x is getting overwritten by the loop values. Your code should look like this

```
for i in range(1, x + 1):
    output += str(i) + "| "
    for y in range(1, x + 1):
        output += str(y * i) + " "
    output += "\n"
```

Comment: No, with ```\t```, it was printing the ```\t``` in the output. That's why I skipped it.

Answer (score 1):

you have to take care also of the padding in order to have a good output, also in your first loop you have to change the name of the variable used for iteration:

```
x = int(input("enter a number 1-9: "))


sep = '    '
sep_len = len(sep)
output = '  ' + sep + sep.join(str(e).rjust(sep_len, ' ') for e in range(1, x + 1))
output +=  '\n' + '_' * len(output)


for i in range(1 , x + 1):
    output += "\n" + str(i) + '|'
    for y in range(1, x + 1):
        output += sep + str(y * i).rjust(sep_len, ' ')

print(output)
```

**output** (for x = 5):

```
         1       2       3       4       5
__________________________________________
1|       1       2       3       4       5
2|       2       4       6       8      10
3|       3       6       9      12      15
4|       4       8      12      16      20
5|       5      10      15      20      25
```